# Meaning of if(!$_)

Tags: perl

I have a script in Perl that is reading a file. At some point, the code utilize the following if statement inside a for loop:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i<10 ; $i++ ) {

    $_ = <INPUT>;
    if (!$_) {last;} 
    
...
```

I am new in Perl, so I would like to know the meaning of !$_. In this example, $_ is a line of my file. So, what content the line should have to the if statement be true.

Comment: See also [boolean](https://metacpan.org/pod/boolean) and [perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata)

Comment: It looks like an awkward way to check for end of file. More commonly, that would be done with a `while (<INPUT>)` loop, not a for-loop.

Comment: An awkward structure `if (!$_) {last;}`  better written as `last unless $_`.  Suggestion: google for **perl bookshelf** - you will find it useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `if` condition, what is inside `()`, is evaluated in a [boolean scalar context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Scalar-values) to be tested for "truthiness."  So if it's `undef` or `''` (empty string) or `0` (or string `"0"`) it's false.

That `!` negates what follows it, so `if (!$_)` is true if `$_` is false (`undef` or `''` or `0` or `"0"`).  However, in this case that `$_` is assigned from [`<>` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) so it'll always have a linefeed at the end -- unless the source for `<>` was exhausted in which case `<>` returns `undef`.

So, in this case, that `if (!$_)` tests for whether there is nothing more to read from `INPUT`, and exits the `for` loop with `last` if that is the case.

A few comments on the shown code.

- That C-style `for` loop can also be written as `for my $i (0..9)`, what is considered far nicer and more readable.<sup>†</sup>  See [foreach](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops), and really follow links for [flow-control key-words](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/foreach)
- The piece of code

  ```
  $_=<INPUT>
  if (!$_) { last; }
  ...
  ```

  reads from `INPUT` filehandle and exits its loop (see [last](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last)) once there is end-of-file. (That need not be an actual file but any resource readable via a filehandle.)

  This is clumsy, to say the least; a common way of doing it is

  ```
  while (<INPUT>) {
      ...
  }
  ```

---

<sup>†</sup> So much so that even hard-core compiled languages now have it. The `C++11` introduced the [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```c++
for (auto var: container) ...  // (really, const auto&), or auto&, or auto&&
```

and the standard reference linked above says

> Used as a more readable equivalent to the traditional `for` loop  [...]

Comment: @HenriqueToste Great, I'm glad you like it :)  Let me know if more would be helpful or if questions pop up later.